# Only Showing Timeline in Task List

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-part, jquery, task-list

I know how and find many ways how to hide the timeline from the task list but I don't find where I can just show the timeline and hide everything to the list.

Question: What can I do to show the timeline only (in a web part) then having to show both timeline and the list below?

Comment: Are you using a project site or team site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap It's a team site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, you can use **Timeline webpart** in SharePoint 2013.

Follow below steps:

1. Add a page(or use existing).
2. Edit your page.
3. Add new timeline webpart from content rollup category.
4. Configure data source to your task list.

**Reference**:

[Timeline Webpart in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/timeline-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Does this answers your question?